# MariaDB > Mysql Import - ERROR 1064 (42000) - near 'PAGE_CHECKSUM=1'

Tags: mysql, mariadb

a MariaDB database with tables in INNODB format was backed up to mysqldumb and should now be restored using mysql (ssh).

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 139: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PAGE_CHECKSUM=1' at 
line 10
```

Line 139 says:

```
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin PAGE_CHECKSUM=1;
```

The tables were previously in the Aria engine but are now InnoDB as you can see.

How can I remove the PAGE_CHECKSUM=1? The file is 5GB in size and it would be good if PAGE_CHECKSUM=1 was gone before the mysqldump.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to remove them automatically. https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,645234,645423

Comment: Thank you. Its not on every table. Only on tables with ARIA before. The sql file is 5 gb. How can I remove this in ssh? midnight commander doestn work.

Comment: You could process the file to replace PAGE_CHECKSUM=1 with spaces. You would have to test a small test_table first. Are you on windows, linux or mac?

Comment: Windows10 and ssh Linux. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sed` to remove `PAGE_CHECKSUM=1`:

```
sed 's/PAGE_CHECKSUM=1//' dumpfile.sql | mysql --user username -p --host hostname databasename
```

Comment: thank you, I would prefer this anwser. Seems quick todo. But I got this error: ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 22: No database selected - do you have a idea? I am already in the folder where the sql file (5GB) is located.

Comment: Of course you need to add all the options to the `mysql` command that you were using before

Comment: Or you can get defaults from `.my.cnf`.

Comment: @Barmar - i am not sure that this works. it only change it 1 time per line.

Comment: You can add the `g` modifier if it's multiple times on the line. I didn't think mysqldump would put multiple create commands on the same line.

Comment: This is my command now: sed 's/PAGE_CHECKSUM=1//' mydb.sql | mysql -uadmin -p123456  mydb.sql. I used the same user as for mysqldump. But I get: ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' to database 'mydb.sql' - what do I miss? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you really have a database named `mydb.sql`? It's probably just `mydb`.

Comment: Ok got ya. I have to import the backup with mysql and during the import it will be replaced. In that case you are right, the DB has a different name then the dump name. When I have uploaded into the db with set and I make a dump again, will be the checksum=1 removed or do I have to import the db always with set?

Comment: I tested it. I have to do it always. In that case I need the right syntax for docker. I have: docker exec -i mysql57 sed 's/PAGE_CHECKSUM=1//' mydb.sql | mysql -uroot -pMypw admin_test

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about docker

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to remove those strings from the file using an editor before you can import it. You're right, small-scale text editors probably will have a hard time on a 5GB file. But there are editors that can do it, for instance vim or emacs.

Or you can use `sed` to filter out the strings you don't want:

```
sed -e 's/PAGE_CHECKSUM=1//' dumpfile.sql | mysql ...options
```

(I assume that the string doesn't occur anywhere else in the file, like in the data itself.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you help me with the right syntax? docker exec -i mysql57 sed 's/PAGE_CHECKSUM=1//' mydb.sql | mysql -uroot -pMypw admin_test. I have the error sed: can't read mydb.sql: No such file or directory, but I am already in the right folder

Comment: Confirm: `docker exec mysql57 pwd` and `docker exec mysql57 ls`.

Comment: Sorry, I dont know exactly what do confirm.

Comment: Run the commands I just gave you. This is to confirm that you are in the directory you think you're in when you run the docker command, and that the files you think are there are in fact present.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I am in the folder :/var/docker/mysql57 and in the folder is that sql file. Is it possible to use sed without uploading at the same time? Just a local replace of the file?

Comment: Sed just reads the file argument as its input. In that way it's like other commands like `grep` or `cat`. I don't know why you are getting an error reading it. That's something you'll have to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

use sed on linux like:

```
root@localhost:~# sed -i 's/ PAGE_CHECKSUM=1;/;/g' page.sql
```

this will first change your file. backup before